# HQL to retrieve list of distinct entities in many to one relationship

Tags: hibernate, hql, many-to-one

In my application users can generate requests for things so I have two entities Request and User mapping to underlying tables of the same name. There is a many to one relationship such that a user can make many requests. My Request entity therefore looks like this

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="request")
    public class Request implements Serializable {
        private int id;
        private User requester;

        @Id
        @Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
        public int getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name="REQUESTER", nullable=false)
        public User getRequester() {
            return this.requester;
        }
    }
```

I need to get a list of of all users that have made at least one request.

I have tried the following:

```
    public List<User> retrieveAllRequesters() {
        return hbSession().createQuery("select requester from Request r left join r.requester as requester").list();
    }
```

but this returns an entity for each request

I tried adding the **distinct** keyword like this:

```
       select distinct requester from Request r left join r.requester as requester
```

but that resulted in an HQL syntax error

I tried quite a few other things, changing the **left** join to **inner** and **outer** but without success.

I'd appreciate a suggestion for the HQL to do what I need. Thanks.

Bohemian has suggested that this could be a dialect problem so I have enabled hibernate.show_sql and it is showing the following:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        distinct user1_.ID as ID10_,
        user1_.EMAIL_ADDRESS as EMAIL2_10_,
        user1_.EXTERNAL_ID as EXTERNAL3_10_,
        user1_.IS_ADMINISTRATOR as IS4_10_,
        user1_.IS_SUPERVISOR as IS5_10_,
        user1_.IS_TECHNICIAN as IS6_10_,
        user1_.LAST_CHECKED_IN_AT as LAST7_10_,
        user1_.LAST_LOGGED_IN_AT as LAST8_10_,
        user1_.LAST_UPDATED_AT as LAST9_10_,
        user1_.NAME as NAME10_,
        user1_.UI_PREFERENCES as UI11_10_ 
    from
        request request0_ 
    inner join
        [user] user1_ 
            on request0_.REQUESTER=user1_.ID
2255 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 421, SQLState: S0001
2255 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
```

The database is MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

With HQL, you don't need to "join" - it's *already* implicitly joined. Try this:

```
return hbSession()
   .createQuery("select distinct r.requester from Request r")
   .list();
```

#### Edited

From the recent addition to the question, the key point of which is:

```
The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable
```

it seems like yet another bit of lame code from microsoft `*sigh*` (every database I've ever worked with can handle it - this is just another reason why I've never used MS SQL)

You'll have to either change the datatype of the `text` column(s) to varchar(something), *or* use `substring(1, n)` on them (in HQL) to shorten them to something that poor MS SQL can "compare"

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that but I got the SQLGrammarException that I get when I add the **distinct** keyword. I don't get the exception if I remove the **distinct** but then I get a row for every Request

Comment: That should work (it has worked for me in the past). Sounds like a bug or a dialect mis-match. What DB are you using and what dialect?

Comment: MS-Sql Server (recent version) the dialect is org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

Comment: As long as `requestor` is a single object (not a set etc) this should work. I don't know what more to say apart from "good luck"

Comment: I have enabled hibernate.show_sql and it shows some more information that I will add to the my question

Comment: Your answer is definitely useful so I have marked it up. I tested this with MySQL and it does work, so this is an issue with SQL Server. I'm not strong in SQL but it looks like it could be testing for **distinct** on all the User fields, not just the ID field. This would explain the SQL Server error due to the UI_PREFERENCES field being "text".
Is there any way that I can do the **distinct** on the ID field only? Maybe involving a sub query?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Bohemian for pointing me in the right direction. His excellent answer deserves some more voting up.

Yes, it was a limitation of MS SQL Server, specifically its inability to handle "text" fields with **distinct**, but it was more that I didn't understand that **distinct** will compare all fields in the entity it is returning, not just the ID field.

The answer for me was therefore to reconfigure my HQL so that it only returned the fields I was interested in, not the entire User entity. Here is what it looks like now:

```
    public List<Object[]> retrieveAllRequesters() {
        return hbSession().createQuery("select distinct r.requester.id, r.requester.name from Request r").list();
    }
```